# If the dinosaurs and man co existed, why did the dinosaurs perish?

Tags: creation

According to the Young Earth Creationism viewpoint, the dinosaurs and man co existed. In this viewpoint, how did the dinosaurs perish? What caused them to be eliminated?

Comment: 25And God made the beast of the earth after his kind, and cattle after their kind, and every thing that creepeth upon the earth after his kind: and God saw that it was good.26And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth.

Comment: For evidence on the coexistence of dinosaurs and mankind, you may be interested in this site that shows ancient artistic depictions of dinosaurs--my mankind:  http://www.genesispark.com/exhibits/evidence/historical/ancient/dinosaur/  The coexistence of men and dinosaurs based on this evidence should be considered a scientific fact.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE! When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). DJClayworth's edits made this much more on topic!

Comment: Can you please describe where you believe that they co-existed?  I don't believe anyone on either side of the fence believes that the Fred Flintstones area was literal.

Comment: YECs definitely believe they co-existed! They were both created on the 6th day.

Comment: Why should the YEC view of the dinosaurs' extinction be different from that of mainstream scientists, among whom there are multiple (similar) competing explanations? Unless a reason is given, I'm inclined to close this question because it has more to do with science than with Christianity.

Answer (score 2):

Joseph C. Dillow wrote a book, *The Waters Above,* about a possible water canopy above the earth that was the source of the downpour. The entire book was an attempt to scientifically measure any of its effects on earth today.

He speculated that with the water canopy, there would be more weight on us and dinosaurs. Based on what we know about hyperbaric healing after surgery, that extra pressure caused longer life for humans and allowed the vaster dinosaurs better blood flow. Once the canopy emptied, lifespans shortened and large dinosaurs could not survive.

I'm not sure the water canopy is a valid theory anymore, though.

[One interesting tidbit in the book was that after the flood event, Noah got drunk (Gen. 9:21). Dillow noted that the lesser pressure causes faster fermentation than normal, so Noah may have thought he was drinking something milder at the time.]

One thing about dinosaurs: Whenever we see or read about them, the huge lizards inevitably figure prominently. Yet bones of these monsters account for a fraction of 0.01 of skeletons found. The vast amount of prehistoric beings found were shellfish and animals no larger than sheep. Quick -- what are today's largest known animals you can think of off the top of your head? Not many, huh? So it was in the ancient world. Sorry to digress.

Comment: Canopy is valid!

Answer (score 1):

The normal young earth creationist perspective is that a few factors resulted in their demise:

1. A lack of biodiversity after flood, and a lack of food in general, put a lot of pressure on them
2. Humans hunted them because they were big and tasty

Comment: flood? How come Noah did  not take them on the arc?
hunting? How come humans were able to wipe every dino out?

Comment: Noah did take dinosaurs on the flood, the issue is the plants they ate. The earth in general was much less lush. People can be pretty persistent ;)

Comment: Noah didn't have to take the big Grandaddy dinos on the ark....Just the little tackers would have been fine. Would have made it more comfortable for everyone.

Comment: Just to note, human bones and dinosaur bone have never been found at the same size / co-mingled.  There is no *scientific* information which confirms that they existed at the same time or that humans ate them.

Comment: If your downvoting this answer can you please explain why? You may not agree with the YEC position but this is what they believe.